# Creating A window using x library programming for C programming

Tags: c, xlib

I am trying to create a window using X11/Xlib in C. My main goal is to make a GUI interface for my program that is below. (Note: I already have attempted to code for the window but it keeps saying that I do not have a monitor or saying that there is a segmentation fault.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include<X11/Xlib.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        Display *Monitor;
        Window DrawWindow;
        GC WindowGC;
        Monitor=XOpenDisplay(NULL);
        if (Monitor == NULL)
        {
            printf("Unable to open graphic display\n");
            exit(0);
        }

        DrawWindow=XCreateSimpleWindow(Monitor,RootWindow(Monitor,0),
                10,10,
                100,50,
                2,
                BlackPixel(Monitor,0),
                WhitePixel(Monitor,0));

        XMapWindow(Monitor,DrawWindow);
        XFlush(Monitor);

        sleep(10);
        XCloseDisplay(Monitor);

        int return_val = 0;         
        int pin_number = 5309;
        int usr_pin = 0;
        int valid_pin = 0;



        // Pin # Validation
        while(1)        
        {
            printf ("\nPlease enter the 4 digit pin number:\n");
            return_val = scanf("%d", &usr_pin);

            while (getchar() != '\n');  /* Clear keyboard input buffer */

            if((pin_number > 999) && (pin_number < 9999))
            {
                if (return_val == 1)
                {
                    while(1)
                    {


                        if(usr_pin != pin_number)
                        {

                            //while (getchar() != '\n');  /* Clear keyboard input buffer */
                            printf("Incorrect Pin\n");
                            printf("Re-enter pin number");
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            valid_pin = 1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (valid_pin == 1) {
                break;
            }
        }


        // Successful account setup prompt
        printf("\nPin Correct!\n");
        printf("Pin #: %d\n", pin_number);
        printf("Have a nice day.\n");

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Second parameter to `RootWindow` should be `DefaultScreen(Monitor)` (btw calling display 'monitor' isn't a good idea. It is, well, `display`). Aside from that, other things looks ok. What is exactly your problem? Where have you got segfault (use debugger please)? Do you have X server launched and `DISPLAY` environment variable set correctly?

Comment: Thanks for responding! As for the naming conventions I was just going off what my but said but I have changed it. As for the second parameter do you mean having it like `(Display,RootWindow(Display,DefaultScreen(Display))` or `(Display,RootWindow(Display,0),DefaultScreen(Display)`.

Comment: The Segfault occur right on the `DrawWindow=` line if I omit the previous IF statement. As for X server and the Display environment I have not read about those so I do not know how deal with either.

Comment: If `XOpenDisplay` returns NULL - it means it cannot connect to X server. I see 3 possible reasons - `DISPLAY` is set wrong and it tries to connect to somewhere non-existent (it should be set to `:0` in most of the cases), X server is not running or it declines your connection because e.g. you haven't passed authentication. What is your environment, where is X and how you launching your program (i mean, from `xterm` or something like this)?

Comment: I am accessing the server remotely through putty and winscp on my school's Linux drive

Comment: This changes the core of the question. But ok, judging by named programs, i assume you use windows. Then how have you compiled program that uses X11 protocol and then launched it (well, maybe you use cygwin, but for some reason i doubt it)? And even so, how (or _where_) do you want to see window opened by your program?

Comment: Yes I am currently on windows but when I use putty, it access the server in the same manner as using a terminal on a networked linux os, it is essentially just a remote access of that, I can use gdb, vi, etc. All that I am wanting however is it to be just a basic window similar to that of a dialogue box if that makes any sense as once I get a window I will then display the text of "Type a pin", "incorrect pin" and the user input.

Comment: And sorry I kind of missed your question a bit, If possible I would like it to display in the middle of what ever computer the program is being run from

Comment: Your understanding is completely wrong. `printf` and `getchar` are stdin/stdout (standard input and standard output - text one), they don't interact with X in any way. `putty` is `ssh` client - which stands for 'secure shell'. Shell, not X - it does _not_ provide X implementation. Shell is text one, you cannot see any X displays here - only text and maybe pseudographic (depends on actual terminal capabilities). So, as your server doesn't run X, there is nowhere your program can connect to. Everything works as it should.

Comment: And for the full picture - `ssh` _could_ redirect X sessions to your machine, so you could run program on remote and see it's window on your local display. But your machine don't have X server running either.

Comment: Alrighty! This makes a lot more sense, I apologize for wasting your time!

Comment: To clarify more - all that you see in `putty` have nothing to do with X. Some kind of pseudographic could be used with libraries like `ncurses` - maybe that would be enough for you.

Comment: ncurses? I don't believe I have ever worked with that, how could I go about that?

Comment: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot display X things throught a putty windows.
You have to make your Message box with [Termcaps](http://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termcap-1.3/html_mono/termcap.html) or [NCurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) library.

If you have a XServer on your computer, you can use the XClient on your distant computer for creating windows on your current computer by the way...
But this is far more complicated than just create a windows and you need a good knowledge in Xlib

(Sorry for my bad english)